# Directive with input and form validation issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with a lot of input field. I've thought that a good idea will be refactor a group of fields that I use frequently and bounded all related fields in a directive. So my form is something like this:

```
  <form name="aForm">
     <input type="number" name="aValue" ng-model="aValue" min="1" max="10" ng-class="{'has-error' : aForm.aValue.$invalid}"/>
     <directive directive-model="anotherValue"></directive>
  </form>
```

The `directive` tag, put two tags `input` pretty similar to the one of line 2.
When validation happen everything is work fine. The problem is that only first input field is successfully colored with the `has-error` class ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vGvmhnvcfEyDicqsPXxC?p=preview)). Why this happens? How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive gets an isolate scope. So you could (in your template) wrap the form controls inside an ng-form directive and do the validation on that form:

```
<ng-form name="directiveForm">
  <input 
    type='number' 
    name='anotherValue' 
    min='1' max='10' 
    ng-model='anotherValue.first' 
    ng-class="{'has-error' : directiveForm.anotherValue.$invalid}" />

  <input 
    type='number' 
    name='aSecondValue' 
    min='1' max='10' 
    ng-model='anotherValue.second' 
    ng-class="{'has-error' : directiveForm.aSecondValue.$invalid}" />

</ng-form>
```

Comment: Another alternative would be to reference the parent: `ng-class="{'has-error' : $parent.aForm.aValue.$invalid}"`

Comment: @Matt : One of the nice things about directives is that they are reusable. If you reference a specific form in the directive, you are restricted to using it on that form only.

Comment: Fair enough. In terms of correctness I would believe the above solution to be more correct (use of ng-form).